# Reading csv file and want to skip first two columns

Tags: python

I am trying to read a CSV file in Python. Further I want to read my whole file but just don't want first two columns. Also I don't have columns name so that I can easily drop or skip it.

What code do I need to read the file without reading first two columns?

I have tried below code:

```
with open("data2.csv", "r") as file:
    lines = [line.split() for line in file]
    for i, x in enumerate(lines):
        print("line {0} = {1}".format(i,x))
```

I am just reading file line by line from above code. But how to skip first two columns and then read the file? I don't have names of the columns.

Comment: In the general case, parsing a CVS file is more complex than you might think.  You run into quoting issues and such.  Unless you've been specifically instructed to NOT use a library, I suggest you look into the Python CVS module.  You'll be able to slurp the file in a few lines and then build whatever you want out of the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) module in the standard library. You might need to pass additional `kwargs` (keyword arguments) depending on the format of your csv file.

```
import csv

with open('my_csv_file', 'r') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    for line in reader:
        print(line[2:])
        # do something with rest of columns...
```

Answer (score 1):

if the lines list does getting the data you want you can use slicing to get rid of the columns you don't want:

getting rid of first two:
`lines[2:]`

getting rid of last two:
`lines[:-2]`

```
with open("data2.csv", "r") as file:
    lines = [line.split()[2:] for line in file]
    for i, x in enumerate(lines):
        print("line {0} = {1}".format(i,x))
```